# restful_authentication nothing appears

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have followed the basic instalation ( http://railscasts.com/episodes/67-restful-authentication )

Doing this:

1.)  ruby script/generate authenticated user sessions

2.) ruby script/generate authenticated user sessions **and** rake db:migrate

3.) On the file **application_controler.rb** I have included

```
include AuthenticatedSystem
```

4.) On the file **routes.rb** I have included

```
 map.signup  '/signup', :controller => 'users',   :action => 'new'
 map.login  '/login',  :controller => 'session', :action => 'new'
 map.logout '/logout', :controller => 'session', :action => 'destroy'
 map.activate '/activate/:activation_code', :controller => 'users', :action => 'activate', :activation_code => nil
```

The problem is that on *localhost:3000/* appears the same usual "
**"Welcome aboard You’re riding Ruby on Rails!"** page.

How do I put the login page appearing on *localhost:3000* ?

Answer (score 9):

Remove the public/index.html from your rails application and Change your routes.rb

map.root :controller => 'session', :action => 'new'

Comment: Didnt Work ... What can I do ?

Comment: use 
map.root :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new' 
since your following  tat railcasts video , If still doesnt work check out with the folder permissions and try executing ruby script/server instead of script/server , Good lucj

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your routes.rb:

```
# You can have the root of your site routed with map.root -- just remember to delete public/index.html.
map.root :controller => 'session', :action => 'new'
```

There's probably a commented out `map.root` in your routes.rb file already.

Comment: Didnt Work ...  What can I do ?

Comment: Did it not work as in made no difference whatsoever? Or not work as in returns an error?

My 'session' controller is actually 'sessions' and I was just using 'sesson' because that's what you had in your code. Maybe worth trying :controller => 'sessions' if you're getting an error "uninitialized constant SessionController". Otherwise it would be useful to know how it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

have you got

```
before_filter :login_required
```

in every controller that requires authentication.
Also as Srinvis mentions above if you are getting a "Welcome aboard You’re riding Ruby on Rails!" message you need to delete the public/index.html file. Make sure its deleted from the filesystem and not just textmate (if your using textmate that is)